# SOQL Query to extract certain attachments fails

Tags: soql, query, sql, sosl, workbench

I want to export attachments of those Owners who belong to a certain Organisation.

I tried:

SELECT BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE OwnerId.Organisation_Name__r = 'ExampleCompanyName', but got the following error:

ERROR at Row:1:Column:41
Didn't understand the relationship 'OwnerId' in the field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming there is a field on `User` called `Organisation_name__c`*

You have:

```
SELECT BodyLength 
  FROM Attachment 
  WHERE OwnerId.Organisation_Name__r = 'ExampleCompanyName'
```

The relationshipname from `Attachment.OwnerId` is called `Owner`, not `OwnerId`

so, you need:

```
SELECT BodyLength 
   FROM Attachment 
   WHERE Owner.Organisation_Name__c = 'ExampleCompanyName'
```

The `TYPEOF` (polymorphic) syntax is only relevant when the sobject can be owned by either users or queues - but `Attachment` can never be owned by a queue

Comment: Are you sure that OwnerId is not a polimorphic field on the Attachment object? And we shouldn't use TYPEOF there?
SOAP API Developer guide [says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) it's polimorphic and refers to calendar and user.

Comment: Good point -I was not aware of the Event relationship.  TYPEOF is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
SELECT BodyLength,
  TYPEOF Owner
    WHEN User THEN Organisation_Name__c
  END
FROM Attachment
WHERE OwnerId IN
    (
    SELECT Id
    FROM User WHERE Organisation_Name__c = 'ExampleCompanyName'
    )
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm

Comment: Hey, thank you for your quick reaction. Unfortunately, I get this error:
No such column 'Organisation_Name__c' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: What is the exact name of the "Organisation Name" field on the user object?
Are you sure it's Organisation_Name__c ?

Comment: I am sorry, it is Organisation_Name, but still, I get the error:

BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE Owner.Organisation_Name = 'ExampleCompanyName'
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:41
No such column 'Organisation_Name' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I don't get it because there is no entity called name.

Comment: This one will work, I recreated this in one of my orgs. I will change my first answer accordingly 

SELECT BodyLength,
  TYPEOF Owner
    WHEN User THEN Organisation_Name__c
  END
FROM Attachment
WHERE OwnerId IN
    (
    SELECT Id
    FROM User WHERE Organisation_Name__c = 'ExampleCompanyName'
    )